# Access __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, eventvalidation

In [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), is it possible to get the values of __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION hidden fields into a variable in C# (server side) in, let's say, overriding the `Render` method?

I have tried:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

    base.Render(htmlWriter);
    string temp = stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This gives me the entire ASP.NET output. We can get the values by using a string function, but I did not find it a very clean solution. Is there a better way to do this?

What I actually want is the values of __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION when the first request is made and not after the postback is done. That is when the output stream if formed when the first request is made.

Comment: They should be available in the Request.Form collection. Have you tried Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"] and Request.Form["__EVENTVALIDATION"]

Comment: Yigit Yener, thank you for the answer. Actually want I is a bit different. I have rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `Page` class using Reflector, you'll see these hidden fields are created during the render phase (look at the methods `RenderViewStateFields` and `EndFormRenderHiddenFields`).

You could probably get at some/all of the data using reflection (e.g. the internal property `Page.ClientState`).

But I don't think there is a clean solution (though to be honest I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Joe, thanks for the reply. I am trying to restructure the output a bit, that is why I need access to the hidden fields. I will have a look into the methods mentioned above and get back.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get the value of __VIEWSTATE by using the above methods. I still have no idea regarding __EVENTVALIDATION ... any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

To get the event validation you should use HTML Agility Pack.

```
var eventValidation = HapHelper.GetAttributeValue(htmlDocPreservation, "__EVENTVALIDATION", "value");

public static string GetAttributeValue(HtmlDocument doc, string inputName, string attrName)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='" + inputName + "']");
        if (node != null)
        {
            result = node.Attributes[attrName].Value;
        }


    return result;
}
```

Comment: jdMiami, thanks for the answer. I had asked this question a long time ago. Let me verify and get back to you.